# Does django have the same level of code generation like Rails?

Tags: python, django

Does django have the same level of code generation like Rails?

In rails you can create models, which then create database migrations.
You can generate controllers, views using the command line.

Answer (score 2):

Django has a very similar way of handling database migrations. They are created by calling `python manage.py makemigrations` and applied with `python manage.py migrate`

Controllers (urls.py) must be added manually to each app, but by typing one import statement they are ready to be used.

Views are made automatically when an app is initialized. However, they are empty, so creating a app does not give you the automatic CRUD html that rails does. There is [generic class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/) in Django which have most of data management done for you, along with automatic form generation, but this requires some actual coding albeit very little.

TLDR: In terms of prefab code generation, Rails wins, but any experienced Django developer can include generic views and forms to get the same functionality in minutes.